# I want to remove a blank space that appears in my responsive banner image

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have a banner which contains a background image that I want to be responsive and appear the same on any device, that's why I have made background-size = 100% , but the problem is that a blank space at the top and the bottom of the background image appears that I want to remove, but without success. I have tried a lot of propositions in some other questions in relation with that, but It is not working. I am a beginner in CSS, can someone help me to find the perfect solution for a problem like that?

Bellow, you will find the code of my banner and 2 pictures explaining what I have got.

This is the banner's html code:

```
<div class="bannercontainer">
    <div class="banner" data-fullscreen="on" data-auto="true" data-hidetimerbar="off" data-fullscreenoffsetcontainer=".header">
        <ul>
            <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="7" data-saveperformance="on" class="background" style="background-image: url(images/slider/test.png); background-size: 100%">
                <div class="tp-caption sft large_bold_white"  data-x="left" data-y="center" data-hoffset="500" data-voffset="-85" data-speed="700" data-start="700" data-easing="easeOutBack">Welcome</div>
                <p class="tp-caption fade" data-x="left" data-y="center" data-hoffset="500" data-speed="500" data-start="900" data-easing="easeOutBack"></p>
                <a href="#slide-under" class="tp-caption sfb btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-wide slider-scroll" data-x="left" data-y="center" data-voffset="80"  data-hoffset="500" data-speed="300" data-start="1000">Read More</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The first picture show the background image that fits perfectly 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rp1S8.jpg

But in mobile device, I only want to remove the blank space
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6zx9.jpg and keep the background image like that.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Is there CSS behind the referenced classes in your HTML (e.g. `banner`, `background`, ..)? If you: please post a _full_ working example (all HTML + CSS involved) as we can only guess about how these other classes influence the HTML rendering.

Comment: Hello sir, thank you for your help, can this image help you ? https://imgur.com/a/X1G6miN

Answer (score 0):

what if you just set the height to 100% instead of the entire image:

```
height: 100%;
```

or you could just set the background to red so it doesn't look like blank space:

```
background-color: red;
```

Comment: Hello , thank you for your help sir, I have made height 100% (the blank is removed but the image doesn't still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following CSS:

```
.bannercontainer .background{
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This makes image fill in any empty spaces and trim the image when necessary.

Edit: Actually it looks like you're already using it. By the images it looks like your sizing of child elements e.g. `.banner`, `<ul>` or `<li>` is not 100% height. Use F12 to inspect elements. Hover over the elements to see their sizes on the page. The one that wraps only around the image probably needs to be set to `position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; margin:0; padding: 0;`

Comment: Hello, I appreciate your analyse, here is the css of the banner, I have tried your code, but doesn't work. the Height 100% instead of background-image 100% make the image fit the banner, but it doesnt appear like what I want